# Code Review: Is this a clean way to write unit test for exception should be thrown case?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

Can anyone here comment on the quality of the above test case? I am here testing for the exception should be thrown scenario. I mean it works but Is it the correct way to unit test for the scenarios where the expectation is that exception should be thrown.

```
it('should throw exception if config.env.json is malformed', async () => {
  // Arrange: beforeEach
  const fakeFsStub = sinon.stub(File, 'readFileAsyc');
  fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.json').returns(mockConfig);
  fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.test.json').returns(FakePromise.resolve(`{"key"}`));

  try {
    // Act
    await Configuration.getConfiguration('test');
    chai.assert.fail('test case failed: [should throw exception if config.env.json is malformed]');
  } catch (e) {
    // Assert
    chai.assert.equal('SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 6', e + '');
  }
});
```

Comment: for code reviews ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: moved the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203520/writing-unit-tests-for-exception-should-be-thrown-case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review. It was even already moved: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203520/writing-unit-tests-for-exception-should-be-thrown-case

Comment: @brandizzi sure go ahead!

Comment: @VishalAnand I did! This comment is automatically generated by the system. If it did sound weird, that's why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like have to write in a multiple failure clauses. I think it makes the test harder to read. Also, I would adjust the structure of your tests.

```
describe("Configuration class", ()=>{
  describe("#getConfiguration", ()=>{
    describe("When the config.env is correctly formed.", ()=>{
      // do some setup and assertions
    })
    describe("when the config.env.json is malformed", () =>{
      let actualError
      let fakeFsStub
      before(async ()=>{
        fakeFsStub = sinon.stub(File, 'readFileAsyc');
        fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.json').returns(mockConfig);
        fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.test.json').returns(FakePromise.resolve(`{"key"}`));

        try {
          await Configuration.getConfiguration('test');
        } catch (e) {
          actualError = e;
        }
      })

      it('should call fs.readFileAsyc with correct args', ()=>{
        // make an assertion
      })
      it('should throw an exception', () => {
        chai.assert.equal('SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 6', actualError + '');
      });
    })
  })
})
```

This is just the way I prefer to write unit tests because it keeps my it's to a single assertion. This makes it helpful when you see a test failing and you know exactly which assertion is causing it to fail. Also, when your setup logic throws an error and causes your tests to fail, the console output will say it failed in the before block.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Definitely good points to take away from here. I also liked how you wrote your describe statement. I, however, have seen and written describe statements differently where each of the `describe` would represent method under unit test and then `it ` will cover scenarios. For ex: describe('getConfiguration', () => { 
   it('should throw exception if config.env.json is malformed', async () => {  ... });
 }); 
Thoughts?

Comment: I do that too. But I nest my describes. I will edit my post to show you what I mean.

Comment: too late to ask but I just now noticed that you have used `#getConfiguration` in second describe. Is `#` a common convention in js world to denote function name or is it only your preference or company you work in?

Comment: I don't know if that is a common convention, but I got that from a few coworkers and it kind of stuck. Since we were working in the same projects we kind of just agreed on that convention.

Answer (score 1):

making function async means it will return promise instead of immediate value.

So with the help of [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) you can doing like:

```
it('should throw an exception', async () => {
    await expect(Configuration.getConfiguration('test')).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith(Error, 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token }');
});
```

Also in my mind this way you actually check if native JSON.parse works well rather testing your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add my own answer as well :) I ended up refactoring my test following the suggestions from here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203520/writing-unit-tests-for-exception-should-be-thrown-case

Also, I like the suggestion of the accepted answer. I might use that while writing my future tests.

```
it('should throw exception if config.env.json is malformed', async (done) => {
  // Arrange: beforeEach
  const fakeFsStub = sandbox.stub(File, 'readFileAsyc');
  fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.json').returns(mockConfig);
  fakeFsStub.withArgs('./src/configuration/config.test.json').returns(FakePromise.resolve(`{"key"}`));

  chai.assert.throws(() => {
    // Act
    Configuration.getConfiguration('test').catch((e) => {
      chai.assert.instanceOf(e, SyntaxError);
      chai.assert.isTrue(e.toString().startsWith('SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON'));
      done();
    });
  });
});
```